# How long to sail from the Yucatán Channel to Belize City?

Tags: sailing

In an approximately 90’ long, two masted topsail schooner how long would it take to sail from the Yucatán Channel to Belize City in July/August?

My best guesstimate, assuming an average cruising speed of 6 knots, would be about 48 hours, but I’d love anecdotes from anyone who has *actually* made the trip.

Also helpful would be any dangers to watch out for (reefs, etc.).

I’m not actually planning on doing this trip, this is just research for a creative writing project.

Answer (score 2):

There are a many variables in any sailing passage estimation, such as wind direction strength which will vary over the course of the passage, tidal currents, and of course the chosen path through all that.

There are some great tools that can help a lot with passage estimation. One free one is the [OpenCPN weather routing plugin](https://opencpn.org/OpenCPN/plugins/weatherroute.html) and there are other commercial options. My favourite is the openCPN one because it's possible to base the predictions on your own boat's (and crew's) previous performance based on a [polar chart](https://www.nauticed.org/sailing-blog/how-do-polar-plots-work-on-a-sailboat/). This can also be created with another free [OpenCPN plugin for recording polar charts](https://opencpn.org/OpenCPN/plugins/polar.html).